# angular.js and node.js calling node on page load

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am trying to call a node function when loading a page with angular, but for some reason the function does not get called. I have the ng-app and controller specified and I figured I would just put the api call in the controller constructor. Here is the code for the page:

```
<!doctype html>

<!-- ASSIGN OUR ANGULAR MODULE -->
<html ng-app="landingPage">
<head>
    <!-- META -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Optimize mobile viewport -->

    <title>my page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="core.js"></script> 

</head>
<!-- SET THE CONTROLLER AND GET ALL GATEWAYS -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">
```

And then my core.js file  is in the same directory which holds the controller has the controller:

```
var loadingCtrl = angular.module('landingPage', []);

function mainController($scope, $http) {
    console.log('loading gateways');

    // when landing on the page, get all gateways and show them
    $http.get('/api/gateways')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.gateways = data;
            console.log('got response');
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });

}
```

I never see any of the log statements....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to change

```
function mainController($scope, $http) {
  //your code here
}
```

to

```
angular.module('landingPage').controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
   //your code here
});
```

To let angular know the controller exists.

Comment: other option is angular.module("landingPage").controller("mainController", mainController); after the named function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try array notation for dependency injection like below.

```
angular.module('landingPage', []).controller('mainController',['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log('loading gateways');

    // when landing on the page, get all gateways and show them
    $http.get('/api/gateways')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.gateways = data;
            console.log('got response');
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
}]);
```

Check the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fzCYwouuE5L6jS7eEU3o?p=preview).
But I would suggest to use factory service for loading external data instead loading it inside controller as you can reuse the same service in different controllers.

Sample code with factory service

```
'use strict';
angular.module('landingPage', []).controller('mainController',['$scope','$http','gatewayService', function($scope, $http,gatewayService) {
    console.log('loading gateways');

    // when landing on the page, get all gateways and show them

    $scope.gateways = gatewayService.getData();

}]).factory('gatewayService', ['$http',function($http){
    return {
        getData: function() {
            return $http.get('/api/gateways')
              .success(function(data) {
                  return data
                  console.log('got response');
                  console.log(data);
              })
              .error(function(data) {
                  console.log('Error: ' + data);
                  return data;
              });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Check [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Eb6JUCN7bTbk3bG1Ev7b?p=preview)